# Repeated error handling

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, dry

So in my vb.net application, i've got alot of try and catch blocks for error handling, especially whenever my app talks to the db.

i'm running through a series of if/elseif statements to see if

```
    ex.tostring.contains("Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts")
```

and various bits like that.

At the minute, I wrote this out and copy and pasted it into each catch, but I know there will be a much more efficient way to do this whereby the code is just in one place and called as and when required.

I tried to implement it as a function, but I had trouble passing info to the function.

So i thought I'd ask and see how you guys go about doing this?

Comment: And what do you want to do If the exception contains that text?

Comment: I'm working on retry functionality so that if the error is a db error then I can check they have an internet connection and if not, switch to offline mode. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need multipe try...catch statements for a program. One is enough.
If i understood you correctly, you want to print or show the error that occured inside the Try block.

```
Public Sub main()
    Try
        'Do something
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Try
        'Do something else
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    If ex.tostring.contains("something") than
End Sub
```

Instead you can do something like this:

```
 Public Sub main()
    Try
        'Do all your code here.
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

In this part, the compiler will automaticlly print the error occured in the program.

Comment: If you are looking to catch the different types of exceptions that can be thrown, a Try block can have multiple `Catch` statements. The `Catch ex as Exception` is a generic way to catch any exception, however if you wanted a different action based upon the exception being thrown, you can put in another `Catch` statement before the generic. This type of methodology is used the eat non-important exceptions that can occur while actually taking action on the ones that are relevant to your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform some action based on the type of exception thrown. Checking the text if not recommended as this could change with a new version of .net or mysqldata

Try something like this:

```
Try
   '
   ' Programming lines of code
   '
Catch exError As MySqlException
   ' an error occurred with MySql
Catch e As Exception
   ' a General error occurred
Finally
   ' Cleanup custom and unmanaged resources if necessary
End Try
```

Have a look at the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/ebonat-exception-error-handling-implementation-in-vbnet-apps.html#Structured) for their recommendations